# Как создать двумерный ArrayList

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции, arraylist

Нашел в нете пример:
`List<ArrayList<Passenger>> dispatchStoryContainer = new ArrayList<>();`,
 но не понятно, как оттуда доставать и туда добавлять значения. Я хотел вот так:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
          for (int k = 0; k < 11-1; k++)
              dispatchStoryContainer.get(i).get(k).add(passenger);
      }
```

Но так нельзя, выходит исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Index 10 out-of-bounds for length 10 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Precon‌​ditions.java:64) a
```

Comment: Что значит «так нельзя»? Как заполняете `dispatchStoryContainer` и что происходит когда пытаетесь к нему обратиться?

Comment: Я имел ввиду вот так делать нельзя: .get(i).get(k).add(passenger);

Comment: Что значит «нельзя»? Распишите какие ошибки возникают. Исключение о котором Вы написали в комментарии к ответу тоже приведите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я Вас правильно понял, то я накидал рабочий пример. Вот он.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ArrayList<Passanger>> arr=new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            ArrayList <Passanger> arr1=new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=0; j<2;j++){
                Passanger pass=new Passanger();
                arr1.add(pass);
            }
            arr.add(arr1);
        }

        Passanger pass=new Passanger();
        arr.get(1).add(pass);
    }
}
class Passanger{

}
```

Так делать нельзя, метод add() применим ко всему ArrayList(), а не к элементу ArrayList()'а

```
dispatchStoryContainer.get(i).get(k).add(passenger);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71349/discussion-on-answer-by-kostya-m----arraylist).

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatchStoryContainer.get(i).add(passenger);
```

Comment: Выходит исключение, я уже пробовал. А если get(k) - то не выходит, и результат почти правильный.

Comment: Весь код приведи